# Pigeonhole principle application sums and differences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let $A \subset \{1,2,...,99\}$, prove or disprove the following:

**a.** For $|A| = 27$
**b.** For $|A| = 26$

There are $2$ different numbers in $A$ that their sum or their difference can be divided with $50$.

I am sure the question points me to use *Pigeonhole Principle*, but I'm not quite sure which are the pigeons and which are the holes because the question deals with *or* so proving that a sum (or a difference) can be divided with $50$ closes the proof without handling the other case.

I've started with saying that there are $(99+98)-(1+2)+1=195$ different sums,
and $(99-1)-(1-99)+1=197$ differences (including negatives) in $\{1,2,...,99\}$.
Also, when dividing with $50$ you can get maximum 50 remainders (let $r \in \{0,1,...,49\}$ mark the reminders)

Can anyone hint me with how to proceed from here?

Comment: How about considering the members of A (mod 50)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the set I've mentioned? $\{0,1,...,49\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the sets:
$\{1, 49, 51, 99 \},
\{2, 48, 52, 98 \}, \{3, 47, 53, 97 \}, \ldots, \{24, 26, 74, 76 \},\{25, 75 \}, \{50 \}$.

Comment: How do I generate those sets systematically? I can write a $10 \times 9$ table and circle the sums that can be divided with $50$ but I'm looking for an elegant proof.

Comment: $\{a, 50-a, 50+a, 100-a | a \in \{1,2,...,25\}\}  \cup \{50\}$? :-)

Comment: @Georgey It is worthwhile to point out that these are the sets $A_i$ such that $a \in A_i \Leftrightarrow a \equiv \pm i \pmod{50}$. So your initial guess is close, you just needed to account for the sum, as opposed to just the difference.

Comment: What does the LHS of the *iff* means?

Comment: All in all it means that by using *PHP* that  __a.__ $\left \lceil \frac{27}{26} \right \rceil = 2$ is a proof while __b.__ $\left \lceil \frac{26}{26} \right \rceil$ is a disproof?

Answer (score 1):

Every element of your set {1... 99} is either in A or A' (complement of A) You can pigeonhole more efficiently by considering which elements cannot be in the same set, then demonstrating that the requirements for how many elements are in A are violated.

So for example: If 1 is in A then 99 and 49 and 51 must be in A'. Try to continue this line of argument.

Comment: Why would $99,49$ and $51$ be in $A'$? Because their sum/difference with $1$ makes it divisible by $50$? I'm not sure I understand which elements are supposed to be in $A'$.

Answer (score 1):

For part b) consider the set $A = \{n \mid 25 \leq n \leq 50\}$. It has $26$ elements and no sum or difference of two different elements is divisible by $50$.

For part a) consider the remainders of $\pm a$ ($\bmod$ $50$) for all $a \in A$,  so $54$ remainders in total.  Therefore there must be at least four pairs $$(a_1,b_1), (a_2,b_2), (a_3,b_3), (a_4,b_4)$$ with $a_k \in A$ all distinct and either $b_k \in A$ or $-b_k \in A$ such that $a_k-b_k$ is divisible by $50$ for $k \in \{1,\dotsc, 4\}$.  If $b_k \in A$ then $b_k \neq a_k$ since each number in $A$ is used only once.  The only possible pairs that do *not* lead to a solution are $$(25,-25), (50,-50), (75,-75)$$ since for these pairs the same number from $A$ is used twice. So there must be at least one pair left that leads to a proper solution.

Comment: How come there are $54$ remainders? Aren't there 50 remainders in $\mod50$?

Comment: @Georgey Each $a \in A$ gives two (one from $a$, one from $-a$) and $|A|=27$.

Comment: Right, and how did you use the PHP to show that there are 4 pairs?

Comment: @Georgey There are $50$ holes for $54$ pigeons, so at least four pigeons have to go into a hole that was already occupied.

Comment: I must be too tired and totally wrong but doesn't the PHP means that there are at least $\left \lceil \frac{54}{50} \right \rceil = 2$ pigeons that will go to an occupied hole?